# how to display the employee number whose data is not found in exception block in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare 
    type empid_list is table of emp.empno%TYPE;
    empno empid_list;
    job emp.job%type;
    empname emp.ename%type;
begin
    empno :=empid_list(7839, 7698, 7782, 7499, 7522);
    for i in empno.first..empno.last loop
    select job, ename into job, empname
    from emp
    where emp.empno =empno(i);

    dbms_output.put_line(
    to_char(empno(i)||': '||job||', '||empname)
    );
    end loop;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    --dbms_output.put_line('No data found for employee '||empno);

end;
/
```

There is an error in the commented line. 
I want to display the employee number. How to do it?

Comment: Should your code continue with the next employee or stop as it does now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the exception handler inside the loop:

```
BEGIN
    empno :=empid_list(7839, 7698, 7782, 7499, 7522);
    FOR i IN empno.FIRST..empno.LAST LOOP
    BEGIN
        SELECT JOB, ename INTO JOB, empname
       FROM emp
       WHERE emp.empno =empno(i);

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(empno(i)||': '||JOB||', '||empname) );
     EXCEPTION
       WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data found for employee '||empno(i));
     END;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply declare a local **variable** to store the passed value and assign it inside the **FOR LOOP**. Since, you cannot refer the **iterator** value outside the **scope of the loop**.

For example,

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2  TYPE empid_list IS TABLE OF emp.empno%TYPE;
  3    empno empid_list;
  4    job emp.job%type;
  5    empname emp.ename%TYPE;
  6    v_empno emp.empno%TYPE; --> Added a variable
  7  BEGIN
  8    empno :=empid_list(7369,9999);
  9    FOR i IN empno.first..empno.last
 10    LOOP
 11      v_empno := empno(i);
 12      SELECT job, ename INTO job, empname FROM emp WHERE emp.empno =empno(i);
 13      dbms_output.put_line( TO_CHAR(empno(i)||': '||job||', '||empname) );
 14    END LOOP;
 15  EXCEPTION
 16  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 17    dbms_output.put_line('No data found for employee '||v_empno); --> Use the variable
 18  END;
 19  /
7369: CLERK, SMITH
No data found for employee 9999

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**Update** If you want to continue the loop even after the exception is raised, then you could **wrap** the **SELECT INTO** statement within a **BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END** block.

Basically, moving the EXCEPTION handling inside the FOR LOOP.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2  TYPE empid_list IS TABLE OF emp.empno%TYPE;
  3    empno empid_list;
  4    job emp.job%type;
  5    empname emp.ename%TYPE;
  6  BEGIN
  7    empno :=empid_list(9999, 7222,7369);
  8    FOR i IN empno.first..empno.last
  9    LOOP
 10      BEGIN
 11        SELECT JOB, ename INTO JOB, empname FROM emp WHERE emp.empno =empno(i);
 12        dbms_output.put_line( TO_CHAR(empno(i)||': '||JOB||', '||empname) );
 13      EXCEPTION
 14      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 15        dbms_output.put_line('No data found for employee '||empno(i));
 16      END;
 17
 18    END LOOP;
 19  END;
 20  /
No data found for employee 9999
No data found for employee 7222
7369: CLERK, SMITH

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use exception block in loop-

```
   dbms_output.put_line('No data found for employee '||empno(i));
```

or else **you should declare separate variable of emp.empno%TYPE to store the empno** which you are accessing. Then it will help to print value in Exception block.

Comment: `empno(i)` No, you cannot refer the iterator value outside the scope of the loop. It will throw a compilation error.

Comment: yes you are right, it is showing error.. Can we write exception block in our loop.??